# How to maintain session in mobile sites when cookies are disabled?

Tags: jsp, mobile, cookies, aem

Cookied are disabled in most of the mobile browsers. If there any Java-JSP based application uses cookie to cache the data, then how would that work on the mobile browser ?
How mobile sites work without cookies and URL rewriting ? I mean how do they maintain session data ?

Also, Since CQ does not support session OOTB, then how CQ mobile sites works which need to cache some data ?

Comment: If you can assume HTML 5, there's always local storage...

Comment: What are the other ways ?

Comment: It's possible to send a cookie session ID via a query parameter rather than a cookie. How do you mean that CQ5 doesn't support sessions out of the box?

Comment: CQ does not provide any capability to maintain session using jsessionId. There is no server side session management.However we can use cookie to do the client side session. Also since there is no jsessionId so we cannot use this to append to URL.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net solves this by passing a session id in query string.